# Does linked server COLLATION COMPATIBLE property guarantee filter execution at linked server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The 4 part naming conversion query is written as:

```
Select col1, col2
From LINKEDSERVERNAME.dbname.dbo.tblname
Where col3 = 'some value
```

Does linked server COLLATION COMPATIBLE property setting to True guarantee the filter (where clause) execution at linked server? Or is there still chance that all data will be pulled and filter will be applied locally? Any official documentation link to support the answer will be helpful.

Comment: Collation has absolutely nothing to do with whether data is filtered locally or remotely; collation refers to the codepage format, case sensitivity and ordering implementation for character sets.

Comment: I am not sure about this but I am guessing that SQL Server will filter out the data at source for the specific collation you use in your query. A simple test would be to run profiler and see what query is being passed to the source sql server and see what rows are being filtered. I am going for the filtration at source but it will be interesting to know the results once you have done the testing :)